# How to make button macro that fill cell with word "group" for next empty row when click

Tags: excel, vba

How to make button macro that fill cell with word "group" for next empty row when click

I wanted to make a button that when it is click, it will write "group" in an empty cell. when i click again, it will look for another empty cell of the same column. The number of row is unknown as the list can get longer. The starting of the list is at cell C5. If possible, not active cell and active sheet.

- Workbook name is TEST.
- The button is on SHEET1.
- The list is on SHEET2.
- The list start at C5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub GroupButton()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("SHEET2")

'If the list is empty, then write "GROUP" in the first cell of the list
If ws.Range("C5").Value = "" Then
    ws.Range("C5").Value = "group"
'Otherwise, write to the next empty cell
Else
    ws.Range("C" & ws.Range("C5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 5).Value = "group"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet2.range("C500000").End(xlup).offset(1,0).Value = "Group"
```